# How to persist data after an update with ChangeNotifierProxyProvider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Here are 2 providers Person and Job. Job depends on the person.

```
class Person with ChangeNotifier {
  Person({required this.name, required this.age});

  final String name;
  int age;

  void increaseAge() {
    age++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Job with ChangeNotifier {
  Job(this.person);

  String career = "na";

  addCareer(value) {
    career = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  final Person person;
  String get title {
    return '${person.name}, $career, ${person.age}';
  }
}
```

Here is how these two providers are initialized with ChangeNotifierProxyProvider

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Person>(create: (_) => Person(name: 'John', age: 25)),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Person, Job>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => Job(Provider.of<Person>(context, listen: false)),
          update: (BuildContext context, Person person, Job? job) => Job(person),
        ),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here is the initState function that initializes the career field in the job provider.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  final job = Provider.of<Job>(context, listen: false);
  job.addCareer("Accountant");
}
```

Now when these lines are executed, it prints "*title: John, Accountant, 25*"

```
String title = context.watch<Job>().title;
print("title: $title");
```

Then if this line is executed, it updates the age in Person but the career in Job is lost. It seems like the Job provider is reinitialized and didn't hold on the latest data.

```
context.read<Person>().increaseAge();
```

Executing these lines again, will give "*title: John, na, 26*", The age is increased to 26, but the career is lost.

```
String title = context.watch<Job>().title;
print("title: $title");
```

**How can I persist the career in Job provider when the age in Person provider is increased?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update of `Job` recreates the `Job` object:

```dart
          update: (BuildContext context, Person person, Job? job) => Job(person),
```

So you might want something like this:

```dart
          update: (BuildContext context, Person person, Job? job) => job?.setPerson(person),
```

And add a `setPerson` method to the `Job` class.

Comment: This is reinitializing the data which is something I want to avoid, anyway to persist the previous data because there was no change to it. In this example, the data is just a string value for the career property.

Comment: @s-hunter I will update my suggested solution a bit!